What is $ \int_{0}^{\exp(-1)} \frac{\ln \ln \frac{1}{x}}{1+x^{2}} dx $?
Background
According to p. 22 of the following paper by Blagouchine, we have the following Malmsten integral evaluation: $$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln \ln \frac{1}{x}}{1+x^{2}} dx = \frac{\pi}{2} \ln\left( \frac{\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(1/4)} \sqrt{2 \pi} \right). \tag{1} \label{1} $$
This identity can also be found on p. 570 of the seventh edition of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's  Table of Integrals, Series, and Products (entry 4.325.4).
When we set $f(x) := \frac{ \ln \ln \frac{1}{x} }{ (1+x^{2})}$, then $f(x) = 0$ at $x^{*} = \exp(-1) = e^{-1}$.
I wonder whether the following integral can be evaluated:
$$ A:= \int_{0}^{\exp(-1)} \frac{\ln \ln \frac{1}{x}}{1+x^{2}} dx. $$
Question

What is the closed-form of $A$?


I get
$$\dfrac{\pi}{2}\left(\dfrac{\Gamma(3/4)}{\Gamma(1/4)}\sqrt{2\pi}\right)+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\mathrm E_{2n}}{(2n)!}\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$$
I doubt there's a closed form for the second term.
Other integral representations of that sum are
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\operatorname{sech}(xy),\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy\enspace\text{ or }\enspace \int_0^1\dfrac{\mathrm{gd}(y)}{y}\mathrm dy$$

@Conreu Interesting, could you tell me what the $E_{2n}$ are?

I don't think that equation is true, after a numerical check of Wolfram Alpha. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi%2F2+%28sqrt%282pi%29gamma%283%2F4%29%2Fgamma%281%2F4%29%29 and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+ln%28ln%281%2Fx%29%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29+from+0+to+1

@Accelerator you're missing the logarithm in $1$st link.

Another way is $A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\text{Ei}(1-2n)}{2n-1}$ via the Ei function

@MaxMuller $E_{2n}$ are Euler nunbers. Also, you and I were missing a logarithm in the result of the original integral from the paper you mentioned. I noticed thanks to @ Accelerator .
